# Can a button delete itself via a function? Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, removechild

I am creating a reset button, that when clicked should delete itself via a function.

But the deletion works only when fired by any element other than the button itself :(  I mean the onclick doesn't work right.

function to create the reset button:

```
function createButton(context, id , value ,func)
{
  var button = document.createElement("input");
  button.type = "button";
  button.id = id;
  button.value = value; // text on button
  button.onclick = func;
  context.appendChild(button); // add the button to the context
}
```

the call to the create function:
`createButton(document.body , "resetButton" , "Reset Game" ,  "resetGame();" );`

the reset function which suppose to delete the button:

```
//reminder - id is "resetButton"
function resetGame()
{   
  var resetBottun = document.getElementById("resetButton");
  var parentOfResetButton = resetBottun.parentElement;
  parentOfResetButton.removeChild(resetBottun);
};
```

when I click the button , it should fire the resetGame() function and the button should disappear, but as I mentioned that only happens if I run the resetGame() function from any other place but not the onclick of the reset button.

hope you understand :/

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `button.onclick` needs to be a *function*.

You are assigning `"resetGame();"`, which is a *string*.

Pass `resetGame` instead of `"resetGame()"`.

Comment: Why it doesn't need to passed with parenthesis ? I mean like this:   resetGame()

Comment: @Davis8988 — That would **call** it immediately and pass the return value.